# Request to Parse API using RestSharp.Portable in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library, restsharp

I'm having problems trying to do a GET request to Parse REST API using `RestSharp.Portable` in a PCL Xamarin project.
The problem occurs in the line:

```cs
var result = await client.Execute (request);
```

Throwing an exception and stopping the app (Android).
This is the function i'm using.

```cs
public async Task<EventItem> GetAListOfAllEvents ()
{
    using (var client = new RestClient (new Uri ("http://api.parse.com"))) {
        var request = new RestRequest ("1/classes/Event/2yHLWDUlv3");
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
        request.AddHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader ("X-Parse-Application-Id", "myAppId");
        request.AddHeader ("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "myAPIparseKey");
        var result = await client.Execute (request);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I hope someone could help me, thanks.

Comment: BTW, why don't you use SDK? They have it for Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line.

```cs
request.AddHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Request is failing because of it (probably as you have no actual content in your GET request).

Comment: I tried that but seems to be a problem related with the Execute (request), headers added are needed to api.parse to work.

Comment: On my machine after removing this line I receive Unauthorised (401) error which is fine I have no actual appId/key in code.